# Organs lifespan out of the body

Tags: organs, lifespan

What organ can be conserved outside of the body for the longest time and still function when reimplanted?

Comment: you may want to be more explicit... this is hard to understand...  Do you mean when transported for transplantation for instance?

Comment: Yes it can be. I mean in the any best conditions.

Comment: this is really too vague to answer. I might say cervix since there is an immortal cervical cancer cell line.  It has never died.  really the question is not precise enough for you to get a satisfactory answer.  the cells may live but the organ can lose all its function..

Comment: Sure there are many immortal cancer cell lines. I read in somewhere in the internet mentions that before transplantation, organs lives 4 to 24 hours. I just couldnt find most durable one  on the internet. :)

Comment: It sounds like what you are really asking is "What organ can be conserved outside of the body for the longest time and still function when reimplanted?" - Is that correct? If so, please edit your question to reflect that and provide more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you consider an organ. Typically though it's the cells which require the most metabolic activity which have the shortest life span. The kidney is the most of the major internal organs with up to 36 hours with liver coming second at up to 16 hours.

Comment: ... on ice i think?

Comment: Yes in optimal preserving conditions.